# What would be the color of a CO2 atmosphere

Tags: atmosphere

So I want to make a planet with an atmosphere made of

- 99% CO<sub>2</sub>
- 1% N<sub>2</sub>

It also has a pressure of 1 bar.
Its star is like our sun.
There is not that much dust.

Edit: New calculation it's 0.9 A.U from it's star. See more [here](https://www.quora.com/What-would-the-average-temperature-of-Earth-be-if-the-atmosphere-were-100-CO2/answer/Bradley-Taylor)

What would be the color of this atmosphere?

Comment: Both carbon dioxide and nitrogen are colorless gases. Therefore the appearance of the atmosphere would be subject to the same coloring conditions as on Earth -- depends on how much dust is in the atmosphere, depends on the time of day and so on. (Or did you mean to ask what color would the sky appear to a human on the surface?)

Comment: Welcome Hissy. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. Enjoy the site. I agree with AlexP, it would help answer your question if you were to clarify a bit.

Comment: Will also depend on stellar spectrum peak, distance to parent star etc...

Comment: Color of the atmosphere, or color of the sky? They are very different things.

Comment: An atmosphere with the the same surface pressure could have wildly different depths on planets with different surface gravities. Look at how far Titan's atmosphere extends from its surface for an example. (And for an example of how much trace components could change the appearance.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some shade of blue**

As pointed out in Ash's answer, a 1 bar atmosphere sky will look similar to Earth's, because blue, shorter wavelengths get scattered with higher efficiency.

But the (near-blue) color also depends on the size (r) of the particles, as Wiki states, it could be a different shade of blue for different molecules, a sunny day will always be *around* the blue.. Like dark blue, blue, blue-greenish, violet..

*Factors causing a shortening of the wavelength*

The size of a CO2 molecule 114pm is slightly less than N2 and O2, which are about 150pm. This will cause a CO2 atmosphere to shift deeper into the blue. with shorter wavelengths. Another factor shifting the light toward a darker blue is the absence of N2 green color, which in Earth's atmosphere mixes in with the "Raleigh-blue", causing a longer perceived wavelength. Your planet has very little N2, mixed with a colorless gas, so the peak is absent, yielding a darker blue sky.

*Factors causing a lengthening of the wavelength*

A factor that could lengthen the wavelengths: CO2 is relatively heavy, which will cause a higher concentration (particle density) at lower altitudes. That can cause lengthening of the wavelength, with a relevant shift toward the green/red like Earth's evenings. The lower the temperature, the stronger this effect will be.

Comment: Would the shift be noticeable?  Could you tell the season and/or altitude by the sky's color?  That would be kind of neat.  Great, picturesque vacation spot, just hold your breath!

Comment: Maybe the evening won't reach the red.. it will become green.. with a red hue on the horizon.. I'm not sure about the relevance of particle size.. CO2 is a smaller molecule.. with a  relevant shift toward blue (smaller wavelength) it could go ultraviolet, you can't see the Rayleigh scattering, the sky is dark, or the planet would reflect its own color.

Comment: dark dark dark blue

Answer (score 3):

I have assumed you mean what colour is the sky as seen from the ground. If I'm reading these notes on [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) properly, no guarantees on that front, then the *chemistry* of the atmosphere doesn't make much difference. Pressure and/or the presence of non-gaseous particles does but a gaseous atmosphere at earthlike pressures produces a blue sky. Again I could be wrong, happy to learn something if someone has greater insight.

Comment: Doesn't the ocean play a part in the blue-ness of our sky(which is what I think the op means)?

Comment: @Lemming I think you've got it backward.  The sky is blue even at the center of a continent (or continental scale desert like the Sahara).  If the ocean looks blue, it's because of the sky; otherwise, it'll be very dark green based only on backscattering of light by the water.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Interesting, seems I have a teacher to give a boot print to

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, a planet with

- 95% CO2
- 1.8% N2
- 0.0063 bar
- 1.5 A.U.

Would have an atmosphere like [this](https://mars.nasa.gov/embed/5297/)

https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/nasa-s-curiosity-mars-rover-takes-selfie-with-mont-mercou

Comment: would you be so kind to put a full source link, not only the result of the analysis ? Your picture looks very "reddish" and I wonder if this light brown is a result of Raleigh scattering.. Take into account Raleigh scattering could be quite irrelevant with a pressure of only 0.0063 bar, making other particles, like sand and dust, more relevant. The sky would look like the planet itself.

Comment: Caption should be "NASA provided 'selfie' of Curiousity on Mars". (I'll update a bit later)

Comment: It's 1 bar and it's 1 A.U.

Comment: The light brown usually seen in photos of the martian sky is due to dust-particles. There are other photos showing the blue sky under clearer conditions.

Answer (score 1):

## It depends on the details.

Mars normally has a pinkish sky with [blue sunsets](https://www.digitaltrends.com/news/eerie-mars-sunset-captured-by-nasas-perseverance-rover/) because Mars has fine dust in the air.  A wetter Mars would not have the same coloration.

Earth's sky is "blue", but I think is a difference between the robin's-egg blue of some seasons and the deep almost iridescent hues of late summer in the eastern U.S., where dust from as far away as the Sahara may have an effect.  Sometimes the Sun is golden, sometimes yellow, and sometimes the "White Sun of Russia" shines over some parts of the world as if the color balance were freshly calibrated.

With a CO2 + N2 atmosphere, you have many possibilities for interesting chemistry.  The presence of [titanium dioxide dust in the environment](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms3249), for example, can convert O2 + N2 to nitrogen oxides - which have a brown color.  I don't know how much is known for a nearly pure CO2 atmosphere, but bear in mind that converting some CO2 to O can release oxygen that can go on and do other things.   There is no obvious ozone present, but *something* will end up absorbing some of the UV light.

The main lack here is hydrogen - is there hydrogen in oceans?  The CO2 + H2O could make carbonic acid, which could leach out metal ions with interesting catalytic effects or a direct coloration of their own.