# Can there be an ocean in a CO2 atmosphere?

Tags: science-based, planets, atmosphere, water

See my first question here and other things about atmosphere: [What would be the color of a CO2 atmosphere?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/217664/what-would-be-the-color-of-a-co2-atmospher)

Hi so I have a planet with a CO2 atmosphere so can there be any ocean on this planet?

Comment: What's your prior research? Have you looked at Mars? It's a planet with a CO2 atmosphere and trace amounts of water.

Comment: A soda planet on table X, please :) Seriously speaking, do you have any other requirements on the planet that you want? Average temperature, atmospheric pressure, is it a rocky or a gas giant one, one things like this.

Comment: other things about the atmosphere are here [link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/217664/what-would-be-the-color-of-a-co2-atmospher)

Comment: Short answer: based on that link (Earth-like size and 1 AU distance to a Sun-like star), if there is water, it is all vapors, in a [runaway greenhouse effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_greenhouse_effect). No soda, just a super-heated sauna.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: That of course depends on how much water there is, doesn't it? Boiling the water increases atmospheric pressure, which increases the boiling point and so on. There are 1.4E21 kg of water in Earth's oceans, and only 5.2E18 kg of air in the atmosphere.

Comment: @HissyGaming: I wonder why global warming exists then... You can't just write some chemical equation and assume it happens. It also has to actually happen, for which the balance has to be on the carbic acid side of the equation. However that's not the case in the gaseous atmosphere. So no, no carbonic acid. Go do your homework about atmospheres.

Comment: Earth had a CO2 atmosphere (well 60% NO2 and 40% CO2) before life converted most of it into biomass and oxygen. And it had oceans all during said time period. CO2 does not prevent oceans in anyway

Comment: @AlexP starting with 1 bar of pressure with 99% CO2 and a gravity of 1g (cf link). Granted: if there's more water, the pressure won't stay @1 bar; if there's just some water, it may stay around 1bar. But _irrespective of how much water there is, the amount of CO2 guarantees a greenhouse runaway and ultraheated sauna atmosphere_

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: Unpleasantly hot, yes. But the question is about the existence of liquid water, no matter how hot.

Comment: @AlexP the question was modified from its first incarnation (when I answered). At that time it was "can water exist", not "I can has oceans, please?" Besides, at 374C, you will need 217atm to keep the water in any other state than vapors. If you do have this much pressure, you will have your water as a superfluid. Any atm pressure lower than that will get you gaseous water. So, how low are you prepared to keep the atm's temperature?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: I don't know, or else I would be writing an answer instead of commenting...

Comment: To have water I'll make the planet 27.5 A.U away from the star.

Comment: @HissyGaming ancient earth had as much as 40% CO2 and still had oceans so your math is way off.

Comment: @HissyGaming: IIRC, global warming doesn't increase linearly with the amount of CO2.
It works (simplistically, of course) by blocking outgoing infrared radiation.  At some point there's sufficient CO2 to block everything.   For instance, the atmosphere of Venus is 96.5% CO2, at a pressure of 93 times Earth, so if the response was linear, it would have a greenhouse effect some two million times greater than Earth's.

Comment: @jamesqf So how do I calculate this?

Comment: @HissyGaming: You pick up a text like Pierrehumbert's "Principles of Planetary Climate", and study the equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Too cold

In your other post, you claim your planet has 1 atm of pressure and is 27.5 AU from its sun-like star. At this distance, the planet would be too cold to have liquid water at 1 atm. But just having CO2 in the atmosphere doesn't mean you can't have oceans, it's just that they'd be frozen solid in this particular case. However, if somehow the planet is kept warm by some other means, then you can have your liquid water oceans with a CO2 atmosphere.